# Inverse of Euclidean distance in IDRISI?

Tags: raster, distance, terrset

I am trying to do the reverse / inverse of a euclidean distance in IDRISI (TerrSet). For example, I am doing distance to roads analysis. The output from the distance raster shows roads as 0 and areas closest to roads as 0.1, 0.2, etc and the areas furthest from roads as a very high value. However, I would like the raster to be the reverse of this - the areas closest to the roads should have the highest values and the areas furthest from the roads should have the lowest values.

How do I create a raster that reverses the number in IDRISI?

I would use reclass but this would be difficult to use as the values are continuous and not integers.

Is there a way to do this in reclass or raster calculator that I am not aware of for continuous values without overgeneralizing them?

Or is there a different tool that I can use?

Comment: Asking about IDRISI in a separate question is the right thing to do but please try to focus this down to a single question (count question marks) after describing precisely what you have tried with IDRISI and where you are stuck with IDRISI.

Answer (score 0):

as you mention, you are looking for the inverse, you may use any program with a raster calculator (qgis, grass, r) and calculate the inverse of the value for each pixel, that is, 1/distance.